# proof of total differentiable $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis

proof of total differentiable $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}$

First i calculated the partial derivatives
$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{y(x^2+y^2)-2\alpha x^2y(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha -1}}{(x^2+y^2)^{2\alpha-1}}$
and $\frac{df}{dy}=\frac{x(x^2+y^2)-2\alpha y^2x(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha -1}}{(x^2+y^2)^{2\alpha-1}}$

These are continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ and thus total differentiable.

Now we only look at the point $(0,0)$: $f(t,t)=\frac{1}{2^\alpha t^{2\alpha -1}}$ now we let $t \rightarrow 0$ and $f(x,0) = f(0,y)=0$ so we know that $df = 0Id^{1\times 2}$.
I now want to prove that $f(t,t)= 0 + df(t,t)^T+o(|t,t|)$ and for $t \rightarrow 0$ should $\frac{1}{2^\alpha t^{2\alpha}}$ go to zero and this is not the case so the function is not total differentiable in $0$.

This is what I found, but I do not know if I did every step correct. Can somebody give me some feedback on my method and proof?

Comment: Hello :) At least for $\alpha=0$ it is continuously differentiable in all points. I think, you have to distinguish different cases about $\alpha$ (greater or less than one).
For $\alpha\geq 1$ it is even not continuous?

Comment: Oh yes I see what you mean in my second part of the proof when I use the definition? because if I first look at the points different from (0,0) then my beginning stays the same, or not?